# Bare Minimum of a Pagination?

Tags: php, mysqli, pagination

What's the bare minimum of a pagination in PHP/MySQLi? I have searched online and have tried to learn how to do a pagination but all the examples are huge, so I was wondering if what's the minimum so I can start there and then work my way into understanding them.

Places I have attempted (examples not all that I looked at); https://github.com/BenGriffiths/pdo-mysqli-pagination ; http://bluedogwebservices.com/php-pagination-with-mysqli/ ;

The first one was extremely long (seemingly) but it made sense in parts to me, the second one was shorter but made less sense to me, I haven't though of looking for video tutorials yet so I am going to search for those too.

Comment: Well pagination is not a difficult problem, it's just fairly involved, thus any tutorials on it will feel huge. Could you link to some specific articles/tutorials you've found which you feel are too involved? That might make it easier for people to help refine their answers.

Comment: I added two examples that I looked at.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pagination is relatively simple and I will attempt to describe it in the simplest way I can.

To start off with here are 5 terms or phrases (or parameters) that you will come across in most pagination scenarios:

- Limit (or results per page)
- Offset (where to start the set of results/records from)
- Current page
- Total results
- Number of pages

Take the example query below:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE active = 1 LIMIT 0 , 25
```

In the SQL above (it should work for mysqli):

- 25 => Is the limit (or results per page)
- 0 => Is the offset (i.e start from result or record 0)

which translates into,

```
give me the results 0 - 24, i.e. the first 25 results
```

So, assuming that you had a product table with 1000 records and you needed to display these on a webpage only showing 25 records per page: On your first page these will be the value of the 5 terms above:

- Limit (results per page) => 25
- Offset => 0
- Current page => 1
- Total results => 1000
- Number of pages => total results / limit => 40

Usually the offset is calculated dynamically based on the current page and the limit, so for page 1 of your product results, the offset would be equal to:

```
offset = (current page * limit) - limit
i.e. (1 * 25) - 25 = 0
```

so your mysqli query would be:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE active = 1 LIMIT [OFFSET] , [LIMIT]

i.e. SELECT * FROM products WHERE active = 1 LIMIT 0 , 25
```

Using the same principle for page 2 of your product results, the offset (or start results from) would be:

```
offset = (current page * limit) - limit
i.e. (2 * 25) - 25 = 25
```

so your mysqli query would be:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE active = 1 LIMIT [OFFSET] , [LIMIT]

i.e. SELECT * FROM products WHERE active = 1 LIMIT 25 , 25
```

which translates into,

```
give me the results 25 - 49, i.e. the next 25 results starting from record 25
```

the other terms would have the following values:

- Limit (or results per page) => 25
- Current page => 2
- Total results => 1000
- Number of pages => 40

In most simple use-cases for pagination, the only parameters that change are the offset and the current page. If you introduce filters into your queries then in addition to the former 2, the total results and the number of pages can change as well.

I hope the above explanation has helped to provide you with a basic understanding of pagination.

Comment: Thank you. I believe using this and an example online I can create my own pagination for my website. This is much appreciated and was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

As a matter of fact, databases has not much to do with the pagination *algorithm*. Which is going to be the same, no matter which database or database driver is used, or if even no database involved at all.

As you will see below, database operations will take only 2 calls, using [safeMysql abstraction library](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql) (though you can use whatever you like).
From database we will need the data itself and total number of records.

In order to obtain these, we will use two MySQL features:

- `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` / `FOUND_ROWS()` to get total number of rows
- `LIMIT` clause to limit the amount of selected data,

To display links to pages you will need to know the current page and the total number of pages.

```
<?php
include 'safemysql.class.php';
$db = new safeMysql();

$per_page = 10;

//let's get the page number
$cur_page = 1;
if (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] > 0) 
{
    $cur_page = $_GET['page'];
}

// then define starting record
$start = ($cur_page - 1) * $per_page;

//now let's get the data and total number of rows
$sql  = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM Board LIMIT ?i, ?i";
$data = $db->getAll($sql, $start, $per_page);
$rows = $db->getOne("SELECT FOUND_ROWS()");

//and total number of pages.
$num_pages = ceil($rows / $per_page);

//we have to define this variable to display list of pages
$page = 0;
include 'template.tpl.php';
```

Now, as soon as we have all our data ready, we may let it out, using native PHP as a *template*:

```
Records found: <b><?=$rows?></b><br><br>
<? foreach ($data as $row): ?>
    <?=++$start?>. 
    <a href="?id=<?=$row['id']?>">
         <?=$row['title']?>
    </a>
    <br>
<? endforeach ?> 

<br>
Pages: 
<? while ($page++ < $num_pages): ?>
    <? if ($page == $cur_page): ?>
         <b><?=$page?></b>
    <? else: ?> 
        <a href="?page=<?=$page?>"><?=$page?></a>
    <? endif ?> 
<? endwhile ?>
```

However, this is indeed bare minimum, including no such essential parts like cutting down number of pages displayed and support for additional WHERE parameters.

Answer (score -1):

We'll use the page info from a $_GET script.

```
<?
if(isset($_GET['page'])) {
 $page = htmlspecialchars(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['page']));
}
else {
 $page = 1; //We'll assume that if the $_GET isn't present, the first page will be shown.
}
$perpage = 25; //Number of items per page
$first = (($page-1)*$perpage); //Basically gets the first row of the page.
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT $first, $perpage");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
//Put your output here
}

//Now, we can put our page navigator

$i = 1;
$count = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM table"));
$num = ceil($count/$perpage);
while($i <= $num) {
echo "<a href='/page/".$i."'>".$i."</a> ";
$i++;
?>
```

Comment: Why is everyone using MySQL? I thought that it was depreciated? And I did say MySQLI so please don't put a MySQL answer, thank you. And thank you for attempting to help me.