# Memory Error in PHP Using SQL Query

Tags: php, sql, memory

I have a PHP page that has a search box and searches media from a fairly large database.  I have made it so that if you only put the first 3 characters (e.g. V75) all the V75 tapes are shown (V75000, V75001, etc.).  However when I search just V7 it gives me this error:

`Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 47 bytes) on line 68`

```
    $query->execute(); // LINE 66

    $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // LINE 68
    }catch (Exception $e) // LINE 69
    {
    die('Cant fetch rows.'); // LINE 70
```

I was wondering what I must change for it to display the V7 tapes as well?  
The approximate number of 'V7' tapes is 255000

Comment: What is the approximate number of V7 tapes?

Comment: @YourCommonSense When I run it in SQL Server Management Studio it shows close to 255000 entries.

Comment: So it's perfectly fine, in your mind, to pull 255k entries into a PHP array and then render it in a search box? :)

Comment: So, are you gong to display all the 255000 entries at once?

Comment: Use `fetch` instead, and process line-by-line.

Comment: @N.B. Haha I was going to make into 1000 entries per page..

Comment: @BartFriederichs - or, limit the number of results. Isn't that way better than using fetch and showing entire list?

Comment: @BartFriederichs really?

Comment: @N.B. yes, but who knows what crazy specs he has to deal with?

Comment: [Bare Minimum of a Pagination](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17859649/285587) - this is a generalized example but it can show you the picture

Comment: @BartFriederichs - I think that even you realize, at some level, that you gave a bad advice. And there are no specs or any other bogus excuses to justify for not telling this guy to use pagination / LIMIT in order to avoid this memory error :)

Comment: How would a simple pagination code look like if it were 1000 entries per page and page numbers on the bottom?

Answer (score 1):

Note that, even if you set the PHP memory limit higher to allow for this many results, sending more than 256 MB to the user for a search query will make the request terribly slow if it doesn't even time out.

Use some sort of pagination and [limit](http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm) your queries.

Comment: If I was a user on that site, I wouldn't use that page after the first time unless it was paginated