# How to debug my php code

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pagination, paging

When I have 1 comment in the table it doesnt show anything.
When I have 2 comments in the table it only shows the second one. I guess for some reason it si skipping the first one, can anyone help?
Much appreciated :)

```
require_once('config.php');
            if(!isset($_GET['NewComment'])) {
            echo "<a style='float:right;' href='?NewComment' class='btn btn-primary'> New Comment </a> <br /><br />";
            $per_page = 4;
            $start = 1;
            if(!isset($_GET['page'])) {
            $page = 1;
            } else {
            $page = $_GET['page'];
            }
            if($page <= 1) {
            $start = 1;
            $page = 1;
            } else {
            $start = $page * $per_page - $per_page;
            }
            $next = $page+1;
            $previous = $page-1;
            $GetAllComments = $con->query("SELECT * FROM comments LIMIT $start, $per_page");
            $num_rows = $GetAllComments->num_rows;
            $num_pages = $num_rows / $per_page;
            while($GAC = $GetAllComments->fetch_object()) {
            echo "<div class='well' style='overflow:auto;'> <h3>". $GAC->Title. "</h3>
            ". $GAC->Content. " <hr /> <em> Posted By ". $GAC->PosterName ." </em>
            </div>";
            }
            for($i = 1; $i <= $num_pages; $i++) {
                $pagen = $page+1;
                $pagep = $page-1;
                    echo "  
                    <div class='pagination'>
                    <ul>
                    "; 
                    if($page > 1) {
                    echo "
                    <li><a href='?page=$previous'>".$pagep."</a> </li>
                    ";
                    }
                    echo "
                     <li class='disabled'><a href='#'>$page</a></li>
                     ";

                     echo "
                    <li>  <a href='?page=$next'>" . $pagen . "</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </div>
                    ";
                    }
                    }
                        elseif(isset($_GET['NewComment'])) {
                            echo "
                            <form action='' method='post'>
                            <h4>First Name:</h4><input type='text' name='fname' placeholder='First Name'>
                            <h4>Title:</h4><input type='text' name='title' placeholder='Comment Title'>
                            <textarea name='editor1'>&lt;p&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</textarea>
                            <script>
                            CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
                            </script><br />
                            <input type='submit' name='post' value='Post' class='btn btn-success'>
                            </form>
                                        ";
                                        if(isset($_POST['post'])) {

                    $FirstName = $_POST['fname'];
                    $Title = $_POST['title'];
                    $Comment = $_POST['editor1'];
                    $addcomment = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO comments (PosterName, Title, Content) VALUES ('$FirstName','$Title','$Comment')");
$addcomment->execute();

                                        }
 }
        ?>
```

Comment: Yet another "please debug my code for me" question...

Comment: I tried debugging, sadly no success :(

Comment: Well, you have to ask "how to debug PHP code" question then

Comment: I noticed that if I remove the  LIMIT $start, $per_page then it works correctly, but that breaks my pagination

Comment: it cannot break your pagination as you have no pagination at all, as you have no number of all records

Comment: start for loop from 0 instead of one (for($i = 0; $i <= $num_pages; $i++). This might be the reason it does not pick first record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debugging is very simple thing, in a way. All you need for this is 2 things:

- understanding, what does your code do, and why. This is essential part.
- visual representation of every variable, value or result returned by every statement or function.

Having these two you can easily compare them.

Say, you have PHP program to construct an SQL query. **Did you check the result of this program?** No.
While you should.

So, you have to echo the result out:

```
echo "SELECT * FROM comments LIMIT $start, $per_page"
```

if the query is all right, and it return the right result in console - well, now we have to check the very next variable, `$num_rows`:

```
var_dump($num_rows);
```

Does it say 1 or 2?

... and so on, for the **every** value or statement involved.

Also, your pagination is broken, as you need a number of all records for this. Here is a right [pagination example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17847638/bare-minimum-of-a-pagination)