# Breaking Data into pages using php

Tags: php

I want to break a table of data into Pages so that I don't have to scroll down too much when searching for a record.

Up to now my research has found me some ways of doing this but all of them include about 100+ lines of coding/script.

Now I want to say that I am NOT LAZY, but I do wonder whether this is really neccessary or if there is a shorter and simpler way.
Assuming that I can write a Where clause + IF statement and what else not might be included in getting or posting data with less than 100 lines of script, I can't help to think that it cannot be right having to have such a long script just to add pages to a table of data..

Anyone know a/some good links or easy scripts? Or is this rly something that requires that much script?
Cheers!

Comment: 100 lines? it could be done with less than 10 :-)

Comment: [Here you go with a dozen](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17859649/285587)

Comment: JQgrid: http://www.trirand.com/blog/

Comment: Datatable : https://datatables.net/

Comment: Dear Mr. Your Common Sense,

The link u post here which leads to the forum where you explained a way to do this, U post this:
 "However, this is indeed bare minimum, including no such essential parts like cutting down number of pages displayed and support for additional WHERE parameters."

Does this mean that if I have a Where clause in my table that this will not work? or will it work?

Comment: and here:
"//now let's get the data and total number of rows
$sql  = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM Board LIMIT ?i, ?i";"

What am I to put @ ?i, ?i  ?

Comment: "not lazy" ? google your question or write a nice method to do this and upload it somewhere for other people to use in the future, that's not lazy

Comment: Oh sure , very easy to post a Link and not provide explanation bout it right? If google got me what I was looking for U think I'd be asking here?
Looks to me U just wish to spam this with 600k Rep Instead of something more constructive like a source of information on the topic or something...
U think if I understood what he meant or had Any idea what to do/how to deal with this that I would still ask?
Thnx for nothing I guess! Yall have a nice day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution ..

```
 <?php  

    class Paginator{  
        var $items_per_page;  
        var $items_total;  
        var $current_page;  
        var $num_pages;  
        var $mid_range;  
        var $low;  
        var $high;  
        var $limit;  
        var $return;  
        var $default_ipp = 25;  

        function Paginator()  
        {  
            $this->current_page = 1;  
            $this->mid_range = 7;  
            $this->items_per_page = (!empty($_GET['ipp'])) ? $_GET['ipp']:$this->default_ipp;  
        }  

        function paginate()  
        {  
            if($_GET['ipp'] == 'All')  
            {  
                $this->num_pages = ceil($this->items_total/$this->default_ipp);  
                $this->items_per_page = $this->default_ipp;  
            }  
            else  
            {  
                if(!is_numeric($this->items_per_page) OR $this->items_per_page <= 0) $this->items_per_page = $this->default_ipp;  
                $this->num_pages = ceil($this->items_total/$this->items_per_page);  
            }  
            $this->current_page = (int) $_GET['page']; // must be numeric > 0  
            if($this->current_page < 1 Or !is_numeric($this->current_page)) $this->current_page = 1;  
            if($this->current_page > $this->num_pages) $this->current_page = $this->num_pages;  
            $prev_page = $this->current_page-1;  
            $next_page = $this->current_page+1;  

            if($this->num_pages > 10)  
            {  
                $this->return = ($this->current_page != 1 And $this->items_total >= 10) ? "<a class=\"paginate\" href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?page=$prev_page&ipp=$this->items_per_page\">« Previous</a> ":"<span class=\"inactive\" href=\"#\">« Previous</span> ";  

                $this->start_range = $this->current_page - floor($this->mid_range/2);  
                $this->end_range = $this->current_page + floor($this->mid_range/2);  

                if($this->start_range <= 0)  
                {  
                    $this->end_range += abs($this->start_range)+1;  
                    $this->start_range = 1;  
                }  
                if($this->end_range > $this->num_pages)  
                {  
                    $this->start_range -= $this->end_range-$this->num_pages;  
                    $this->end_range = $this->num_pages;  
                }  
                $this->range = range($this->start_range,$this->end_range);  

                for($i=1;$i<=$this->num_pages;$i++)  
                {  
                    if($this->range[0] > 2 And $i == $this->range[0]) $this->return .= " ... ";  
                    // loop through all pages. if first, last, or in range, display  
                    if($i==1 Or $i==$this->num_pages Or in_array($i,$this->range))  
                    {  
                        $this->return .= ($i == $this->current_page And $_GET['page'] != 'All') ? "<a title=\"Go to page $i of $this->num_pages\" class=\"current\" href=\"#\">$i</a> ":"<a class=\"paginate\" title=\"Go to page $i of $this->num_pages\" href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?page=$i&ipp=$this->items_per_page\">$i</a> ";  
                    }  
                    if($this->range[$this->mid_range-1] < $this->num_pages-1 And $i == $this->range[$this->mid_range-1]) $this->return .= " ... ";  
                }  
                $this->return .= (($this->current_page != $this->num_pages And $this->items_total >= 10) And ($_GET['page'] != 'All')) ? "<a class=\"paginate\" href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?page=$next_page&ipp=$this->items_per_page\">Next »</a>\n":"<span class=\"inactive\" href=\"#\">» Next</span>\n";  
                $this->return .= ($_GET['page'] == 'All') ? "<a class=\"current\" style=\"margin-left:10px\" href=\"#\">All</a> \n":"<a class=\"paginate\" style=\"margin-left:10px\" href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?page=1&ipp=All\">All</a> \n";  
            }  
            else  
            {  
                for($i=1;$i<=$this->num_pages;$i++)  
                {  
                    $this->return .= ($i == $this->current_page) ? "<a class=\"current\" href=\"#\">$i</a> ":"<a class=\"paginate\" href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?page=$i&ipp=$this->items_per_page\">$i</a> ";  
                }  
                $this->return .= "<a class=\"paginate\" href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?page=1&ipp=All\">All</a> \n";  
            }  
            $this->low = ($this->current_page-1) * $this->items_per_page;  
            $this->high = ($_GET['ipp'] == 'All') ? $this->items_total:($this->current_page * $this->items_per_page)-1;  
            $this->limit = ($_GET['ipp'] == 'All') ? "":" LIMIT $this->low,$this->items_per_page";  
        }  

        function display_items_per_page()  
        {  
            $items = '';  
            $ipp_array = array(10,25,50,100,'All');  
            foreach($ipp_array as $ipp_opt)    $items .= ($ipp_opt == $this->items_per_page) ? "<option selected value=\"$ipp_opt\">$ipp_opt</option>\n":"<option value=\"$ipp_opt\">$ipp_opt</option>\n";  
            return "<span class=\"paginate\">Items per page:</span><select class=\"paginate\" onchange=\"window.location='$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?page=1&ipp='+this[this.selectedIndex].value;return false\">$items</select>\n";  
        }  

        function display_jump_menu()  
        {  
            for($i=1;$i<=$this->num_pages;$i++)  
            {  
                $option .= ($i==$this->current_page) ? "<option value=\"$i\" selected>$i</option>\n":"<option value=\"$i\">$i</option>\n";  
            }  
            return "<span class=\"paginate\">Page:</span><select class=\"paginate\" onchange=\"window.location='$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?page='+this[this.selectedIndex].value+'&ipp=$this->items_per_page';return false\">$option</select>\n";  
        }  

        function display_pages()  
        {  
            return $this->return;  
        }  
    }  
    ?>
```

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-paginate-data-with-php/

Have a nice day